# How $timeout and $interval will work together in angular

Tags: angularjs, settimeout, setinterval

I am new to angular and I want to call one function doSomething() for 15 seconds with the interval of 3 seconds.
doSomething() internally call a REST API, I want to call that API in every 3 seconds.

and I want to stop that API call after 15 seconds.

How can I do that through the $timeout and $interval function?

Comment: call function in loop and use $timeout in loop.repeat loop 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only by $timeout:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$timeout) {

var count = 0;
callApi();

function callApi() {

    $timeout(function () {
     if(count < 5) {

         count++;
         callApi(); // call this function again
         console.log("this is"+count+"th loop");
     }
    }, 3000);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use timeout and for loop to achieve this

```
var pull;
function timeOut(i){
  pull = $timeout(function () {
           console.log("put your req "+1)
         },3000)
}

for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
   timeOut(i)
}
```

after the execution finished you can cancel the timeout

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  $timeout.cancel(pull);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $interval is more clear here

```
var intervalTimeSec = 3;
var intervalTimeLimitSec = 15;
var apiCalls = 0;
var intervalId = $interval(function() {
    //call the API here
    apiCalls++;
    if (apiCalls * intevalTimeSec >= intervalTimeLimitSec) {
        $interval.cancel(intervalId); // stops the interval
    }
}, intervalTimeSec * 1000)
```